# Ignore last character when comparing strings

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, string-comparison

I have following strings I want to compare:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(20), @b VARCHAR(20) 

SET @a = '05Y2203-B10'
--SET @a = '05Y2203-B10B'
SET @b = '05Y2203-B10C'
```

When comparing, I want to ignore the last character, but only if the length of the substring after the `-` is 4.

```
'05Y2203-B10B'   --ignore the 'B'
'05Y2203-B10'    --do not ignore the '0'
```

A few examples:

```
'05Y2203-B10B' = '05Y2203-B10B' --match
'05Y2203-B10B' = '05Y2203-B10C' --match
'05Y2203-B10'  = '05Y2203-B10B' --match
'05Y2203-B10'  = '05Y2203-B11'  --no match
'05Y2203-B10'  = '18G9987-B10'  --no match
```

The strings will always look like one of the following patterns:

```
'%-[A-Z][0-9][0-9]'      --without last character
'%-[A-Z][0-9][0-9][A-Z]' --with last character
```

The length of the substring before the `-` can vary.

So far I have this solution:

```
SELECT  1
WHERE   CASE WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(@a, CHARINDEX('-', @a) + 1, 4)) = 4 
             THEN SUBSTRING(@a, 1, LEN(@a) - 1)
             ELSE @a
        END 
        = 
        CASE WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(@b, CHARINDEX('-', @b) + 1, 4)) = 4 
             THEN SUBSTRING(@b, 1, LEN(@b) - 1)
             ELSE @b
        END
```

This works but it's not quite readable, especially if there are more conditions in the query.

Is there a simpler or more elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: What about first part (before `-`)? Does have it the fixed length?

Comment: No the length before the `-` can vary.

Comment: The more elegant way would of course be a better table design :-) If '05Y2203-B10' is a code and 'B' an optional extension to it, then these should be two separate columns rather than one column holding the concatenated code '05Y2203-B10B'.

Comment: Well if I had a nickel for every bad designed table ... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the length of sub-string after `-` is either 3 or 4, you just only fetch 3 characters after `-`. Here is code snippet

```
LEFT(@a, CHARINDEX('-', @a) + 3) = LEFT(@b, CHARINDEX('-', @b) + 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you want more readable (maintainable) query, if so then you can write a simple scalar value function to return the string part you want and hide all of the complexity in that function

Also for having better performance you can define another [`computed column`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) for this trimmed data and store it using that function without trailing data.
The column gets physically stored if you mark it with `PERSISTED`.
When you run query use this column.

Comment: I agree. The removal cannot be done elegantly in T-SQL, so create a function to do it. (In Oracle you would use RTRIM to remove trailing characters, but T-SQL's RTRIM is only capable of removing the space character.)